# I am unable to execute this program

Tags: ruby

> error:C:\Users\RR\Desktop\ruby_sandbox>ruby classes.rb classes.rb:44:
>   syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

my code is:

```
class Animal

attr_accessor :name,:age,:sex,:location


def initialize(age=18,sex="not available",location="not specified")

  puts "details of animal"

  @age=age
  @sex=sex
  @location=location
end

def condition(age,name)
  if animal.age>animal1.age
    puts "#{animal.name } is older than #{animal1.name}"
  else
    puts "animals age are in increasing order"
  end
end
```

Comment: you should add `end`  in the end

Comment: thanks for help..let me check this out..

Comment: Also worth noting that `animal1` is something you're referring to but never gets defined anywhere.

Comment: but let me know , why is there need of an extra "end"

Comment: Why add an "extra" end? Because the language requires it? You have to "end" the class declaration, not only the method definitions. Ruby is telling you that: "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end" means Ruby wants an `end`. The line number you show us in the error isn't correct and doesn't match the code you gave us since it only has 21 lines. Consistency in the errors and the code is really important when asking for help.

Comment: thanks @theTinMan..i have got it..

Comment: i could not post all the lines ..so i omitted the half of the lines to make the codes shorter...

Answer (score 1):

Please take care about your indentation while writing ruby you will see where you missed the `end` keyword.

But in your case the problem is not only about the indentation before start to fix it. You can check some documentation about [Class and Instance Methods in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) or [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/oop2/) can help you in your case.

Good luck.

Comment: Proper indentation cannot be stressed enough. When you get sloppy with your code mistakes happen and they're often really silly ones that could have been avoided by keeping things neat.

Comment: you'r right @tadman.....and thanks thatway_3 for the reccomending those tutorials...